# React js, state won't update with my if and else statements

Tags: reactjs, web

Console just keeps logging BOOM VOOM ? is there a reason for this or is it just not recognising the string value , i'm new to JS and React.

```
constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {
    message: "CLAY"
  }
}

changeMessage = () => {
  let mm = this.state.message
  console.log(mm)

  if (mm = "CLAY"){
    this.setState({
      message: "BOOM VOOM"
    })
  } else {
    this.setState({
      message: "CLAY"
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `mm = "CLAY"` your assigning the value `"CLAY"` to the variable `mm`, so that will always be truthy.

To make a strict comparison use `===` like that:

```
if (mm === "CLAY")
```

Comment: thanks I guess I should go back to JS basics for a refresher

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `re-assign` and `if-else` condition

Use previous state with `&&` would be fine.

```
changeMessage = () => {
  this.setState(prev => prev.message === "CLAY" && { message: "BOOM VOOM" });
}
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      message: "CLAY"
    };
  }
  handler = () => {
    this.setState(
      prev => prev.message === "CLAY" && { message: "BOOM VOOM" }
    );
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.message);
    return <button onClick={this.handler}>{this.state.message}</button>;
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```